# Limit display of char* in natvis file to specific length

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, natvis

I've got a custom data structure holding a `char*` buffer with two lengths associated: maximum and actual length:

```
struct MyData {
  char* data;
  int length;
  int capacity;
};
```

In the Visual Studio (2015) debugger visualizer I only want to display the first `length` elements of the `data` buffer and not the (usually uninitialized) remaining elements.

I've the following rule in my custom `.natvis` file for displaying my custom data structure:

```xml
<Type Name="MyData">
  <DisplayString>content="{data,su}" length={length}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Is it possible to only display `data` as a "`su`"-encoded string from `data[0]` to `data[length-1]`?

Comment: if `data[length]` is `'\0'` then most debuggers won't show anything beoind the \0.

Comment: Unfortunately, this legacy code I'm working on hasn't always \0 terminated strings. I know, a little scary.

Comment: Then I don't see how a debugger is to know the length-in-use is `length`. What you can do is, when allocating the memory, zero it (use `calloc` ot `memset`) so there will be a `\0` (unless `data` is re-used with different lengths in use).

Comment: I know that the member variable `length` is the correct length of used/occupied elements in `data` and I want to display only those. Something in the form of an pseudo-expression of `content={data[0..length-1]}`.

Answer (score 14):

This will limit the length of the string in the debugger:

```
<Type Name="MyData">
    <DisplayString>{data,[length]su}</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

Comment: Explained here: [Format specifiers for C++ in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp?view=vs-2017)